# Different results with same function and argument in c++ code

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I've made a function that calculate chebyshev moment for an image, here is the main code. I have different results with same image, and every time I run I get new values. Here is the functions and the main code.

```
     float calcul_ro(int p,int N)
{int i; float ro_p=1,float_N=(float)N;
if (p==0)
    ro_p=(float)N;
else {
    for (i=1;i<=p;i++)
    ro_p=ro_p*(1-((i*i)/(N*N)));

ro_p=(ro_p*float_N)/(2*p+1);
}
return ro_p;
}
///______________________________________________________________________________///
float calcul_tp(int x,int p,int N,float tp_1,float tp_2)
{float tp, float_N=(float)N;
if (p==0)
   tp=1;
else if(p==1)
    tp=2*x+1-N;
else
    {  //tp=((2*p-1)*tp_1)-((p-1)*(1-(pow((float)(p-1),2)/pow(float_N,2)))*tp_2);
        tp=((2*p-1)*tp_1)-(((p-1)*(1-((p-1)*(p-1))/(N*N)))*tp_2);
    tp=tp/p;}
return tp;
}
///______________________________________________________________________///
float *chebychev_moment(Mat image,int N)
{int p,q,x=0,y=0,i=0,j,compt=0,hml=0; float rslt,alpha_p,alpha_q,beta_p,beta_q,ro_p=1,ro_q=1,tp,tq;
float *vect=new float[55];
float tp_moins_1[100][100], tp_moins_2[100][100], tq_moins_1[100][100],tq_moins_2[100][100];
///******************************************************************
///initialisation de tp_moins_1 
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<100;j++)
       tp_moins_1[i][j]=1;
}
///************************************************************************
for (p=0;p<9;p++)
{
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
            tq_moins_1[i][j]=1;
    }
    for(q=0;q<=9-p;q++)
    {

    ro_p=calcul_ro(p,N);
    ro_q=calcul_ro(q,N);
    ///************************************
    for (x=0;x<image.rows;x++)
        {   y=0;
            tp=calcul_tp(x,p,N, tp_moins_1[x][y], tp_moins_2[x][y]);
            tp_moins_2[x][y]=tp_moins_1[x][y];
            tp_moins_1[x][y]=tp;
                for(y=0;y<image.cols;y++)
                    { if(image.at<int>(x,y)!=0)
                    {tq=calcul_tp(y,q,N,tq_moins_1[x][y],tq_moins_2[x][y]);
                    tq_moins_2[x][y]=tq_moins_1[x][y];
                    tq_moins_1[x][y]=tq;
                    rslt=rslt+tp*tq*image.at<int>(x,y);}
                    }
        } 
///************************
    rslt=rslt*(1/(ro_p*ro_q));
    printf("rslt %d ,p=%d,q=%d, =%f \n",hml,p,q,rslt);
    vect[compt]=rslt;
    compt++;
    rslt=0;

}}
return vect;
}
///______________________________________________________________________________///
int main()
{ Mat image=imread("2_.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
float *vect=new float[55], *vect2=new float[55];

vect=chebychev_moment(image,100);
Mat image2=imread("2_.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
vect2=chebychev_moment(image2,100);

//function that copy the vector in a file
write_on_file(vect,"vector_image3.txt");
write_on_file(vect2,"vector_image4.txt");
return 0;}
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `rslt` in `chebychev_moment` is used before it is set. Probably you forgot to initialise it to `0`. `alpha_p`, `alpha_q`, `beta_p`, `beta_q` are not used at all.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just initialise it to 0  but i have the same problem.

Comment: check the rest of your code for the same kind of bugs. e.g. tp_moins_2 and tq_moins_2 also both are used before they are set.

Comment: can you upload your current code? Did you check for more uninitialised variables? That's pretty much the only source of undefined behaviour in your code that I can see at the moment.

Comment: Yes i've check them all, i've just wrote a small program that count the number of white pixels on my image and i got a different results.                     Mat image=imread("2_.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat image2=imread("2_.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
    {if (image.at<int>(i,j)!=0)
           nbr++;
    if (image2.at<int>(i,j)!=0)
        nbr1++;
    }
}
printf("%d\n %d\n",nbr,nbr1);

Comment: in your example nbr is not declared...
Try to generate a small image (say 3x3 pixel) and check with the debugger, whether the loaded image is the right one. If not, then check your image loading procedure.